# Promises JavaScript

Tags: javascript, promise

I had a little problem today and after hours of useless trying everything coming to my mind I made it work:

```
getItems = () => {
  let diseases = [];
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.itemsRef.on('value', (snap) => {
      snap.forEach((disease) => {
        diseases.push(disease.val());
        console.log("IN-PROMISE",disease.val());
      });
      resolve(diseases);
    });
  }).then((diseases) => {
    this.setState({diseases});
    console.log("ON-THEN",this.state);
  });
}
```

That is the working code. I would really appreciate if someone will explain me why this didn't work because I do not understand how to think about these promises:

```
getItems = () => {
  let diseases = [];
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.itemsRef.on('value', (snap) => {
      snap.forEach((disease) => {
        diseases.push(disease.val());
        console.log("IN-PROMISE", disease.val());
      });
    });
    resolve(diseases);
  }).then((diseases) => {
    this.setState({diseases});
    console.log("ON-THEN", this.state);
  });
}
```

*the only difference is the "resolve" method, its position to be more precise.

** in this second example, the "THEN" will be executed before the promise itself ("IN-PROMISE" console.log fires after the "ON-THEN").

Thank you in advance!

Comment: That means `this.itemsRef.on` is asynchronous. In that case your second attempt shouldn't work either and should always resolve empty array.

Comment: @shawon191 — Note that the second attempt is the one at the top of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`resolve(...)` is how you say "I have done the thing I promised, here is the result".

---

Your first attempt:

1. Create a promise
2. Set up an event handler
3. Resolve the promise *even though you haven't got the result yet*

Later on, the event occurs

1. You loop over the data and do stuff with it

**You resolved the promise before you had the data.**

---

Your working attempt:

1. Create a promise
2. Set up an event handler

Later on, the event occurs

1. You loop over the data and do stuff with it
2. Resolve the promise *and this time you have the data*

Answer (score 1):

*This is the wrong attempt:*

```
getItems = () => {
  let diseases = [];
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.itemsRef.on('value', (snap) => {
      snap.forEach((disease) => {
        diseases.push(disease.val());
        console.log("IN-PROMISE",disease.val());
      });
    });
    resolve(diseases);
  }).then((diseases) => {
    this.setState({diseases});
    console.log("ON-THEN",this.state);
  });
}
```

In this particular example, `this.itemsRef.on('value', (snap) => {})` is an asynchronous function that is executed **when** there is a change in `itemsRef`.

This means that when you call `resolve(diseases)` outside it, the function will not be executed and `diseases` will be equal to the empty array that you have declared.